# Recover images from a digital camera memory card

Tags: data-recovery, camera, memory-card

I tried to connect the digital camera on the computer using USB but then the camera froze, so I tried to turn it off, but it wont turn off so I just removed the battery. When I plugged it in again, the images are gone, lost.

I tried recovering the data using TuneUp Undelete and tried to search for ***.jpg**, but there were no results. What can I do to recover the pictures?

I already tried using:

1. Photorec
2. Recuva
3. TuneUp Undelete
4. Pareto data recovery
5. `chkdsk x: /F`

But none of them worked.  I think I've only lost the data yesterday. And I haven't used the camera. So there's a possibility that it is still there.

Comment: did you only try to connect the camera again; if yes, try to read the card with an external reader. maybe you should add information about the type of card (sdhc is the most common one) and the software you are using to read from the camera - in windows there is a default camera assistant, but there is also proprietary camera manufacturers sw like nikon transfer, and i think that linux just mounts it as a removable media.

Comment: yes, but no luck. I also tried using recuva, but it cannot find any. what can you recommend on this?

Comment: http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-ebook/file-deletion-in-FAT16.htm explains to delete just marks the FAT entry as such, and leaves the data on disk. If the FAT entries were destroyed, recovery apps won't pick up the missing files.

Comment: You should try Minitool Partition Recovery, free for 1GB recovery.

Answer (score 3):

[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) was designed for doing exactly this. It is free, multiplatform and open source.

> PhotoRec is file data recovery software designed to recover lost files including video, documents and archives from hard disks, CD-ROMs, and lost pictures (thus the Photo Recovery name) from digital camera memory. PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been severely damaged or reformatted.

Comment: Wow! That utility does a GREAT job with pics, pdfs, and text files.

Comment: This worked for me for recovering deleted pics on an SD card.

Answer (score 1):

This photo recovery tool for Windows, [PhotoRetrieval](http://www.anysoftwaretools.com/photo-recovery.html), is also free.

> PhotoRetrieval is an easy yet powerful digital photo recovery software to recover deleted photos from both personal computer and portable devices such as digital camera, cell phone, USB flash drive and removable memory card etc.

Just one more tip: before those images are recovered, users should never attempt to take more photo with the digital cameera as chances of recovery may be quite decreased. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [previous topics about data lost from SD cards](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card), I've used [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/) to successfully receover deleted files from an SD card in the past, I've also used it to recover files from a hard drive that Windows couldn't read. So I think it could quite probably do what you're.

It has a free version that scans for recoverable files, but doesn't actually recover anything, so if you give it a go you'll know whether it'll work for you or not without having to hand any money over.

Answer (score 0):

When you pulled the card while in use, those files we're not deleted, but likely converted into lost file fragments, probably why your undelete application did not pick anything up.

I can't promise this will work, but if they *are* lost files, then this will recover them:

Put the camera storage card into a card reader, so it shows as a drive, and from the command line run the checkdisk utility. When prompted to save convert lost fragments into files, choose Yes. It will recover lost file fragments as .CHK files, which are your .jpg files with a different extension. Where x is the card:

For Windows:

```
chkdsk x: /F
```

For Linux:

```
fsck.vfat -af /dev/sdxy
```

Good luck!

Comment: @keyboard monkey: doesn't work, I put it on the sd card reader on the laptop. But it did not prompt to save the files. It just said that there are 16,384 bytes in 1 folder. 
@gathrawn.What do I do? Pareto logic seems to be a bad site. And the software isnt even detecting any file. Its as if its in freeze mode if I try to scan the removable drive.

Comment: If it does not ask to save the files, then it did not find any. Sorry man :/

Comment: `chkdsk X: /F /R` will probably work better.