# How to repair SD card without reformatting?

Tags: partitioning, software-rec, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data from SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)
>   [Is it possible to get back data from a Micro SD which is unresponsive?](https://superuser.com/questions/317916/is-it-possible-to-get-back-data-from-a-micro-sd-which-is-unresponsive)

Something happened with my SDHC card in my phone - after restart it now says "the SD card is blank or has unsupported filesystem". It may be that the card itself is dead or maybe it just somehow got corrupted but the data is still there. I'd first like to try to recover the card without reformatting it so I'm looking for a software (preferably free) that could do it.

To give a few more hints, when I put the SD card into my PC (using Micro-SD USB adapter that came with it) it takes about 3 minutes for the card to even show up as a disk E: and in the disk manager, the volume is detected as "RAW filesystem". I trying TestDisk right now and the partition table type is detected as "XBox" so I'm not really sure if I should proceed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get back data from a Micro SD which is unresponsive?](http://superuser.com/questions/317916/is-it-possible-to-get-back-data-from-a-micro-sd-which-is-unresponsive)  also  http://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card

Comment: How old is the card? These do have a max read/write life to them. You have have reached that point of your SD card.

Comment: It's only about 2 months old and not used heavily. I suspect that the phone crash and SD card malfunction are somehow related as they happened at the same time. But I don't know if the phone crash damaged the card or the card failure caused Android crash.