# how to save an amazing jpeg from the evil grey squares

Tags: data-recovery, jpeg

I just saved over a thousand pictures using the procedure described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/317916/is-it-possible-to-get-back-data-from-a-micro-sd-which-is-unresponsive). However, a few of the pictures have grey areas on them. the thumbnail displays the picture perfectly, but once viewed, the picture contains this grey block. I've tried Irfanview, which didn't help. I've also tried photorescue, which did kind of help, but, requires a key, that i tried to find on the net, but all have expired.

Is there any way to recover the lost JPEGs?

Comment: I probably cannot answer your question, but a corrupt sample image might help others, which you won't bother to make public.

Comment: "*I've also tried photorescue, which did kind of help, but, requires a key, that i tried to find on the net, but all have expired.*" Ask their support to upload more keys to the internet

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I see what you did there...  =D

Answer (score 3):

If it's an option to retry the recovery, try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover your files. It is a companion program to the [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) data recovery software. I used it, and it works wonderfully -- I didn't see a single corrupted image that it recovered, and it recovered more than [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) did did.

The gray squares are actually a symptom of a corrupted jpg file and can't be repaired. The reason the thumbnails are still fine is that, depending on the file type, the thumbnail is stored in the picture and is not corrupted, so it still displays fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went on a journey trying to recover some deleted photos from SD card this morning. First three options I tried listed the files found and then wouldn't recover them without payment. Recuva showed some of the files, but with big grey blocks on some of the jpeg images. PhotoRec found all the pics I wanted.

Comment: I might even send Mr Grenier a token gesture of my thanks. I like the guy who who makes good things and shares to all.