# Undeleting files on android

Tags: data-recovery, android, tablet, nexus-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data from SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)

I mistakenly deleted some files on my tablet's storage (Nexus 7, Android 4.2). Is there a way to recover them?

I would prefer not to root my tablet. I would prefer using a program on my computer that would mount the file system (connecting the tablet to my computer by USB) and then undelete the files on the external storage (sdcard).

The files were voice recording.