# Filesystem on sd-card lost

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, sd-card, photos, testdisk

Last time I want to bring my photos from SD-card (Sandisk Ultra SDHC 32 GB) to my computer (windows), my computer said that there is no file system on the card and I should format the card. Also my camera can´t read the card anymore.

**When I open the format-dialog it said that card has 30,6 MB (not GB).**

I do a backup of the card one day before so I lost "only" one day of photography, but unluckily this is the first birthday of my daughter :-(.

I use a Canon 70D and raw-format so file extension is `CR2`.

So I try some tools to recover, but doesn’t work. In the end I tried `testdisk`, but also without luck. So here is my procedure with `testdisk` I tried, maybe you know a better way which can bring my photos back.

1. `testdisk_win` says card has 32 MB (MB not GB).
2. I chose partition table type `none`

   *-> No pictures were found.*
3. So I changed geometry based on another 32GB-SD-card

   - cylinders changed from 3 to 3905
   - heads (255), sectors (63) and sector-size (512) stay without changes

   *-> Search takes longer, but nothing found.*

**Is there anything else what I can do before I think about to go to a data-recovery-company?**

I think about to format the card and try search again, but I'm not sure I this would bring the final death to the pictures.

Comment: **Do NOT format the card**: it's a write operation, and previous content can easily get overwritten. In fact, you should make sure the physical LOCK switch is slid down so the card becomes read-only. TestDisk allows you to [create a whole disk image](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Image_Creation). This way you get a copy you can mess with without risking losing even more data. TestDisk also comes with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), a file scavenging tool which can be useful if you can't repair/recover the file system.

Comment: @and31415: Tahnks for your quick response. I tried PhotoRec also, but doesn`t bring me a step ahead. Can you recommend some configuration for the tool? I'm aware of the "write operation"-problem, the thought was "better get some of the images is better then none" - a taste desperation :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover data from SD card](http://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)

Comment: @and31415: problem with the diskimage is that it doesn`t give me a 32GB image - only 32MB (as far as I remember). Therefor the "possible duplicate link" doesn`t fit well.

Comment: Well, it's still worth trying. If you can't get a full image you might still work the actual card (as long as it's write-protected). For what is worth, if you were to try to format the card, what would the reported capacity be?

Comment: @and31415: "what would the reported capacity be" - good question. I will try it when I be back home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16240/discussion-between-and31415-and-micha).

Comment: Before you do anything, you should create an image of the card using a tool  like `dd`. Make sure it images the entire card, and not just the reported partition(s). Then work on the image file to recover the data.