# Memory card is damaged, Can I regain data?

Tags: memory-card

While using my tablet it hung up, then a message " Memory is damaged"  appeared, probably due to high temperature!

My question is there any means to regain data from it??

Comment: See if you can read the microSD card on a computer, if it doesn't work, it is highly unlikely to get any data out of it.

Comment: I tried to read it by connecting my mobile phone to the computer but it didn't appear,   is there another way to read it

Comment: @waelkilany It's probably damaged beyond recovery by try as the comment above which sort of suggests a computer with an integrated SD card reader or an USB one. Although trying it with a different mobile device should do as well. If it isn't even recognized (not the same as unreadable) that pretty much confirms my thoughts above.

Comment: @waelkilany What make, model and OS version is the tablet. Also can you confirm you are talking about its built in memory rather then sd card (you tagged the post memory-card which may be a red herring?)

Comment: Lenovo TB-7304I , Android 7.0 , it's an SD card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover data from SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)

Comment: I connected it to the computer by another means, & I could detect it via "cmd" which told me  "CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives".  So How can I change it back to its original type??

Comment: Unfortunately, Photorec didn't recover files for me