# Windows refuses to mount SD Card

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, sd-card

So, I've got an SD card with one partition as FAT32 and a bit of unallocated space:
[image]
Windows can find the device itself. Disk manager can see it:
[image]

(Sorry about Russian, but it is reporting that device is fine, without specifying filesystem)

Problem here is that it doesn't mount the SD card. Disk manager doesn't show partition's letter (as it does with other mounted partitions), and it doesn't show up in the file explorer. There are no driver-releated issues as well, according to the Device Manager. What am I doing wrong? I'm running Windows 10, version 2004. Card itself is 32GB Kingston SDHC.

Update: I tried using it with another Windows 10 PC, and it didn't show up as well. But the camera, where it was originally, reads and writes to it just fine.

Update: I tried formatting the SD card. I deleted volume, and tried to create new one, but it said that "Volume was created, not formatted". If I try to format it using Disk Manager, I get "Unable to find the file" error.

Update: Formatting using camera (which works fine with it) didn't help as well.

Comment: Have you tried reformatting the card in the camera? If you don't plan on ever using this card in a camera again, have you tried reformatting the card in Windows?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick there are some photos I want to retrieve, so formatting would be my last option

Comment: As I could not read the russian in the screenshot, have you tried to manually apply a drive letter to the partiton,Right click on the partition to get the short cut menu. The other option is to connect the camera via usb and read the photos that way into the PC

Comment: @Codebreaker007 when I select "Change disk letter" option it just says that it is unable to find some file. That's weird.

Comment: Try reinstalling the SD-card reader driver or the correct one (not the driver included in windows but form the Laptop/PC manufacturer) If reformatting fails thats normally the issue (missing file is a possible indicator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover data from SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be some kind of Windows bug. I installed Linux (Manjaro) on this PC, and now it reads SD card just fine. As a workaround, you might boot some LiveCD linux and get your files using it.